# PDO PHP Adding "AND" in BetweenPlaceholders

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to add " AND " in between the key and value pair arguments for my sql query but I don't know how. I have tried search the net but unable to find a solution.

```
       $cdatahome = fetchCategory(array("status"=>"1","home"=>"1")); 

       function fetchCategory(array $conditions){
        $db = Core::getInstance();

            $sql = "SELECT id, title FROM ruj_category WHERE ";

            $params = array();
            foreach ($conditions as $column => $value) {
            if (preg_match('/^[a-z-.]+$/', $column)) {

            $sql .= "$column = ?";
            $params[] = $value;

     }
    }           
            $sql .= " order by title asc";  
            $res = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $res->execute(array_values($params));
                $res = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        

            return $res;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cdatahome = fetchCategory(array("status"=>"1","home"=>"1")); 

   function fetchCategory(array $conditions){
    $db = Core::getInstance();

        $sql = "SELECT id, title FROM ruj_category WHERE ";

        $params = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $column => $value) {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-z-.]+$/', $column)) {
        if($i != 0){
        $sql .= ' AND ';
        }
        $sql .= "$column = ?";
        $params[] = $value;
        $i++;
 }
}           
        $sql .= " order by title asc";  
        $res = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $res->execute(array_values($params));
            $res = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        

        return $res;
```

Comment: I think using `implode()` is a more elegant solution

Comment: @Mike I agree! this was the first thing that came to my head

Answer (score 5):

```
$where = array();
foreach ($conditions as $column => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/^[a-z-.]+$/', $column)) {
        $where[] = "$column = ?";
        $params[] = $value;
    }
}
$sql .= implode(' AND ', $where);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when I want to put something like **AND** or **&** (in the case of URLs), I create an array and implode it on the string I want in the middle. For example:

```
$items = array("a", "b", "c");

$output = implode(" AND ", $items);
```

Outputs:

```
"a AND b AND c"
```

In your case, you can do your foreach loop to build the string pieces and then use **AND** as glue in the `implode()` function as listed out by the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could put the conditions into an array, as you do with the values to $params. Like `$cond[]="$column = ?"` and then `$sql.=implode(' AND ',$cond);`

To have it solved in your foreach: before the loop set `$first=false;` and in the loop do `$sql.=($first?'':' AND ')."$column = ?"; $first=false;`